# Background color of nav menu items

Tags: css

UPDATE: For clarity, I added the yellow background color to see what "shows through" or is "transparent"

I can't seem to figure out how to keep the same styling in this nav bar, but make the background color white, not transparent. I'd also like to get rid of the transparency between each of the drop down menu items.

http://jsfiddle.net/trevoray/VZ7qD/20/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Trevor

```
 .nav {
border-radius:4px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 4px #8b8b8b; 
 }
```

Comment: Make the background color of which element white?

Comment: Where is the transparency ?

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue in you fiddle but CSS bckground colors are done like so `background-color:#FFFFFF` - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp

Comment: I want the nav buttons to be white, not transparent. But I need to keep the bottom color of each nav button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `background-color` in following CSS class

```
.nav > li 
{
   background-color:white;
}
```

[JS  Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VZ7qD/23/)

Comment: thanks! i thought that would mess with all the gradient setting of the background, but I should've tried it first. Duh.

Comment: what about the transparency between each drop down menu items?

Comment: For that you need to remove margin-bottom from `li's (.nav li > ul > li)` class. have a look http://jsfiddle.net/VZ7qD/25/. Adrift also mentioned the same.

Comment: yeah, but then that creates a bolder solid line between the two list items. I like the spacing between the list items.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to add a class to each submenu UL and give that UL a background color of white.